# Execute Maven Plugin From Java Code

Tags: maven-2

Hi Friends i am developing a project using maven.I want to execute maven plugins from java code.Please let me know is there any Api is there to configure and execute maven plugin from java code....

Thanks
Kumar

Comment: Can you eleaborate that a little bit more why you wan't to do this? particular reason etc?

Comment: Hi khmarbaise i want to execute my custom maven plugin without specifying it in pom.xml using java code....that is what i asked...

Comment: Just call mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal of your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MavenCli sources](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-embedder/xref/index.html) to see how it initializes required components and executes required goals.